# How to get poetry to switch venvs?

Tags: python, python-venv, python-poetry

As a standard practice, I create a Python venv in my home dir and always use this venv instead of the system Python. This gets around having to `sudo` for `pip install` and has numerous other benefits. I activate the venv in my zshrc file.

Poetry does not play nice with this. It detects that I'm in a venv, assumes that it's a venv dedicated to the current project, and starts uninstalling all of my libraries. That's fine, as I understand it poetry is intended for use with per-project venvs.

However, after creating `~/my-project/venv`, I cannot switch into it:

```
$ cd ~/my-project
$ poetry env use venv/bin/python3.9

Skipping virtualenv creation, as specified in config file.
Using virtualenv: /Users/[USERNAME]/python3-venv
$ poetry -V
Poetry version 1.1.11
```

I can manually activate this venv, but that messes up my shell config. I understand that `poetry env use` is supposed to tell poetry to use that venv. Why is it not working?

Comment: How exactly are you creating the per-project venv?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel `python -m venv venv` - why?

Comment: It's based off the system Python, or the user venv? Not sure if it's relevant, just trying to make sure the situation can be reproduced by others.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Ah, good question. I just tried doing `deactivate` before creating a new venv, and I still have the same symptoms.